# Image Processing: PSNR and MSE alternative method?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, noise-reduction

Assuming random Gaussian noise on an image, how would one tell which denoise method is the best quantitatively?

A lot of papers uses MSE & PSNR. However, lower MSE coulde also mean that not enough noise has been removed, thus I think that the MSE and PSNR aren't really the best way to tell.

Answer (score 1):

A table of the PSNR of the original image and the image after the various denoise algorithms have been applied should be a good method to quantitatively analyze the results of the various methods.  You could also calculate a deltaPSNR between the result and the noisy image.

If you have an original image without noise, you could calculate the PSNR of this image.  Then you could add noise to the image, and again calculate the PSNR.  Finally, after denoising, determine the PSNR again.  This final PSNR can be compared to the original image to see how much like the original each result is.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have noise-free images. So I calculated the PSNR using the denoised and noisy images following the equation on Wiki. However, some of the denoised images with  high PSNR are still quite noisy and not as good as the ones with lower PSNR. So this is why I hope that maybe there's another way to quantitatively analyze the results.

Comment: Is there any sort of brightness shift occurring when the denoising algorithms are applied? Or a change in bit depth?  And are you using the same test image across the whole set of denoising algorithms?  You could try using entropy as a "noise" measurement (average entropy, or total image entropy).

Comment: I don't think there's change in brightness (from looking with my eyes) or bit depth... And yes, I'm using the same test image for every algorithms :)

I have tried the entropy before. I ran into similar problem when the algorithm doesn't remove enough noise (noise entropy is higher than algorithm that removes a bit more noise and the result seems to be better -- also using my eyes to tell)